# The code doesn't give any output

Tags: python, function, operations

I'm trying to do the following in my code:

A man is trying to shoot some balloons with a rock.

1. `a` is the number of balloons in a row.
2. `b` is the speed of the rock the man is trying to shoot with.
3. `c` is the speed that the rock loses after hitting each balloon.

In the end I want to know how many balloon have been shot by the rock.

The problem is that the code doesn't want to give me any output. Please help!

```
def Balloons(a, b, c):
    d = 0
    for i in (0, a):
        b - c
        d = d+1
        if d == int(a):
            print(d)
        if d > int(a):
            d = d-1
            print(d)
        if int(b) <= 0:
            print(d)

x = int(input('give me the number of test cases: '))
for i in range (0, x):
    a = int(input())
    b = int(input())
    c = int(input())
    Balloons(a, b, c)
```

Comment: Did you miss a `range` in `for i in (0, a)`? The line `b - c` does not do anything as well.

Comment: when you take input from the console press `enter` for every input.

Answer (score 3):

## Problems

There is no output because in your definition of your code, it you wrote `b - c` which does nothing. You need to tell Python what to do with the result of `b - c`.

What you should do instead is to use to [subtraction assignment operator](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/subtraction_assignment.html):

```
b -= c
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
b = b - c
```

This will give you some output but not the right output. Another problem with your code is that you missed out the keyword `range` in the for loop of your function:

```
for i in (0, a):
```

What this means in the loop is that `i` will be the value of `0` and `a` then the loop will end. It should be changed to:

```
for i in range(0, a):
```

Lastly, you may want to add some `break` statements which exit the `for` loop so that you only have one output:

```
if d == int(a):
    print(d)
    break
if d > int(a):
    d -=1
    print(d)
    break
if int(b) <= 0:
    print(d)
    break
```

## Final solution

The resulting code using subtraction assignment and addition assignment operators would be:

```
def Balloons(a, b, c):
    d = 0
    for i in range(0, a):
        b -= c
        d += 1
        if d == int(a):
            print(d)
            break
        if d > int(a):
            d -=1
            print(d)
            break
        if int(b) <= 0:
            print(d)
            break

x = int(input('give me the number of test cases: '))
for i in range(0, x):
    a = int(input())
    b = int(input())
    c = int(input())
    Balloons(a, b, c)
```

## Alternative method

However, looking at your problem, it could be solved with basic math, `math.ceil` and the `min` function.

The number of balloons shot through is equals to the smaller of:

1. ceil(Initial speed/Speed loss)
2. Number of balloons

Hence, you can have a much smaller function:

```
import math
def Balloons(a, b, c):
    return min(math.ceil(b/c), a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    b-c
```

I think you want to write `b -= c`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
def Balloons(a, b, c):
    d = 0
    for i in range(0, a):
        b=b-c
        d=d+1
        if d==int(a):
            print(d)
        if d>int(a):
            d=d-1
            print(d)
        if int(b)<=0:
            print(d)

x = int(input('give me the number of test cases: '))
for i in range(0, x):
        a=int(input())
        b=int(input())
        c=int(input())
        Balloons(a, b, c)
```